# Converting two columns of date and time data to one

Tags: r

I have a simple data frame:

```
D <- c("2012/12/14", "2012/12/14")
Time <- c("18:40:37", "18:40:48")
df1 <- data.frame(D, Time)
```

I wish to combine the two columns of date and time information into one, preferable in the format of day, month, year, time.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
R> within(df1, { timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(D, Time)), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") })

           D     Time           timestamp
1 2012/12/14 18:40:37 14/12/2012 18:40:37
2 2012/12/14 18:40:48 14/12/2012 18:40:48
```

Comment: Many thanks @rcs - but how do I get an extra column in my dataframe (df1) with this combined date/time column in?

Comment: I know this comment is two years late, but the answer should really be df1 <- within...

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter alternative could be:

```
df1 <- within(df1, { timestamp=strptime(paste(D, Time), "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S") })
df1
       D     Time           timestamp
1 2012/12/14 18:40:37 2012-12-14 18:40:37
2 2012/12/14 18:40:48 2012-12-14 18:40:48
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$TS <- as.POSIXct(paste(df1$D, df1$Time))
```

This will create an additional column TS in df1 that combines date and time and will be of type POSIXct. You can confirm by

```
str(df1)
```