# Combine date as integer and time as factor to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I know this has been asked several times and I looked at the questions and followed the suggestions. However, I couldn't solve this one.

The datetime.csv can be found on https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bvhk4kei4pg8zq/datetime.csv

My code looks like:

```
jd1 <- read.csv("datetime.csv")
head(jd1)
      Date Time
1 20100101 0:00
2 20100101 1:00
3 20100101 2:00
4 20100101 3:00
5 20100101 4:00
6 20100101 5:00

sapply(jd1,class)
> sapply(jd1,class)
     Date      Time 
"integer"  "factor"

jd1 <- transform(jd1, timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time)), "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I tried the solution suggested by rcs on [Converting two columns of date and time data to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359546/converting-two-columns-of-date-and-time-data-to-one) but this seems to give an error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string you're passing to format includes `%S` which you don't have.  But that won't fix the error since its coming from `as.POSIXct`.  You need to pass the format string there instead and remove the call to the `format` function.

```
foo <- transform(jd1, timestamp=as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M"))
str(foo)
```

Compare this to:

```
bar <- transform(jd1, timestamp=as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
str(bar)
```

And the result of calling `format`:

```
baz <- transform(jd1, timestamp=format(as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format="%Y%m%d %H:%M"), format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
str(baz)
```

Comment: @ Justin : Thank you so much. Thanks for posting examples as well to explain the difference.

Answer (score 3):

if it's just this file you don't even need to read it as csv. Following will do

```
# if you are reading just timestamps, you may want to read it as just one column
jd1 <- read.table("datetime.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character"))
jd1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(jd1$Date.Time, format = "%Y%m%d,%H:%M")
head(jd1)
##       Date.Time           timestamp
## 1 20100101,0:00 2010-01-01 00:00:00
## 2 20100101,1:00 2010-01-01 01:00:00
## 3 20100101,2:00 2010-01-01 02:00:00
## 4 20100101,3:00 2010-01-01 03:00:00
## 5 20100101,4:00 2010-01-01 04:00:00
## 6 20100101,5:00 2010-01-01 05:00:00



# if you must read it as seperate columns as you may have other columns in your file
jd2 <- read.csv("datetime.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character"))
jd2$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(jd2$Date, jd2$Time, sep = " "), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
head(jd2)
##       Date Time           timestamp
## 1 20100101 0:00 2010-01-01 00:00:00
## 2 20100101 1:00 2010-01-01 01:00:00
## 3 20100101 2:00 2010-01-01 02:00:00
## 4 20100101 3:00 2010-01-01 03:00:00
## 5 20100101 4:00 2010-01-01 04:00:00
## 6 20100101 5:00 2010-01-01 05:00:00
```

Arun's comment prompted me to do some benchmarking..

```
jd2 <- read.csv("datetime.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character"))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(as.POSIXct(paste(jd2$Date, jd2$Time, sep = " "), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"), as.POSIXct(do.call(paste, c(jd2[c("Date", "Time")])), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"), 
    transform(jd2, timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")), times = 100)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                                                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##           as.POSIXct(paste(jd2$Date, jd2$Time, sep = " "), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M") 18.84720 18.87736 18.89542 18.93307 20.99021   100
##      as.POSIXct(do.call(paste, c(jd2[c("Date", "Time")])), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M") 18.94440 18.97917 18.99492 19.02220 21.07320   100
##  transform(jd2, timestamp = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")) 19.05581 19.10230 19.12612 19.16877 21.27490   100
```

Comment: `do.call(paste, c(jd2[c("Date", "Time")]))` would be faster.