# R - converting date and time fields to POSIXct with HHMMSS format

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a data file which has three columns thus:

```
20010101 000000  0.833
20010101 000500  0.814
20010101 001000  0.794
20010101 001500  0.772
...
```

As is fairly clear to human eyes, the first two are date and time. I need to convert them into a POSIXct (or something else if it's better, but my limited past experience of dealing with timestamps in R is to use POSIXct). Normally, having pulled it in with read.table, I would use:

```
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

However, the second column seems to lose its leading zeroes (probably through a type coercion?), and thus it doesn't work correctly.

I've looked at [Combine date as integer and time as factor to POSIXct in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367210/combine-date-as-integer-and-time-as-factor-to-posixct-in-r?lq=1) and [Converting two columns of date and time data to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359546/converting-two-columns-of-date-and-time-data-to-one), but both are using times with delimiters such as :, and so don't have the same problem.

How can I convert these columns to a POSIXct, please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were very close.  The following "simply" forces the first two columns to be read as character strings, which saves the leading zeros.

```
R> df <- read.table(text="20010101 000000  0.833
20010101 000500  0.814
20010101 001000  0.794
20010101 001500  0.772", 
+ header=FALSE, colClasses=c("character", "character", "numeric"), 
+ col.names=c("Date", "Time", "Val"))
R> df
      Date   Time   Val
1 20010101 000000 0.833
2 20010101 000500 0.814
3 20010101 001000 0.794
4 20010101 001500 0.772
```

Now what you were attempting "just works":

```
R> df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
R> df
      Date   Time   Val            DateTime
1 20010101 000000 0.833 2001-01-01 00:00:00
2 20010101 000500 0.814 2001-01-01 00:05:00
3 20010101 001000 0.794 2001-01-01 00:10:00
4 20010101 001500 0.772 2001-01-01 00:15:00
R>
```

Comment: I'm doing everything described here and `POSIXct` returns NA

Comment: You may have a factor variable.  Try `anytime::anytime(paste(df$Date, df$Time))` as that will convert a factor variable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had some early times like `600` and all they needed was a `0` in front.

Comment: So you input did not correspond to the format requirement. News at 11pm? Glad you have it working.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to import the data as character:

```
txt <- "Date  Time  value
20010101 000000  0.833
20010101 000500  0.814
20010101 001000  0.794
20010101 001500  0.772
"

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE, 
                 colClasses=c("character", "character", "numeric"))

df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting the answer that came first, but this is substantially the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use lubridate package which is super awesome and fast. for your purpose try this:

```
df <- read.table(text="20010101 000000  0.833
20010101 000500  0.814
20010101 001000  0.794
20010101 001500  0.772", 
                  header=FALSE, colClasses=c("character", "character",     "numeric"), 
                  col.names=c("Date", "Time", "Val"))

df$mix <- paste(df$Date, df$Time)
df$mix <- parse_date_time(df$mix, 'Ymd HMS')
```

Just you have to feed the correct format to it. I prefer it to `as.POSICct`  because it is much more flexible and you have other functions to work with time variables.