# Convert numeric values to dates

Tags: r, date, datetime, zoo, lubridate

I have a numeric vector as follows

```
aa <- c(1022011, 2022011, 13022011, 23022011) (this vector is just a sample, it is very long)
```

Values are written in such a way that first value is day then month and then year.

What I am doing right now is

```
as.Date(as.character(aa), %d%m%Y")
```

but,

it is causing problems (returning NA) in case of single digits day numbers. (i.e. 1022011, 2022011).

so basically

```
as.Date("1022011", "%d%m%Y") does not work
```

but

```
as.Date("01022011", "%d%m%Y")  (pasting '0' ahead of the number) works.
```

I want to avoid pasting '0' in such cases. Is there any other (direct) alternative to convert numeric values to dates at once?

Comment: there are some examples here you might find useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301204/r-converting-date-and-time-fields-to-posixct-with-hhmmss-format

Comment: I guess `130222011` is a typo? It seems that there is an extra digit there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your platform, you could use `sprintf` in order to add a zero at the beginning. It seems that Mac is OK with this, but not windows 7 given the discussion with the OP.

```
aa <- c(1022011, 2022011, 13022011, 23022011)

as.Date(sprintf("%08s", aa), format = "%d%m%Y")

[1] "2011-02-01" "2011-02-02" "2011-02-13" "2011-02-23"
```

**UPDATE**

@CathyG kindly mentioned that `sprintf("%08i",aa)` works on Windows 7.

Comment: I am getting first two as NAs. 0 is not getting pasted. If you run just `sprintf("%08s", aa)' it just adds the space not zero.

Comment: @user3664020 I see. I do not get that on my machine. Let me check.

Comment: That is weird. When i run `sprintf("%08s", aa)` I get a vector `" 1022011" " 2022011" "13022011" "23022011"`

Comment: @user3664020 How about this `as.Date(sprintf("%08s", as.character(aa)), format = "%d%m%Y")`? Could you tell me what happened?

Comment: It is also resulting in the same result.

Comment: I was reading ?sprintf. "0 For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others." I am using Mac. I wonder if platform is the issue here. Are you using OS X?

Comment: yes i think the platform is the issue. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @jazzurro actually this works : `sprintf("%08i",aa)`... (on windows 7)

Answer (score 5):

It could be rearranged using `sub` in which case a plain `as.Date` with no format works:

```
x <- c(1022011, 11022011) # test data

pat <- "^(..?)(..)(....)$"
as.Date(sub(pat, "\\3-\\2-\\1", x))
```

giving:

```
[1] "2011-02-01" "2011-02-11"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dmy` in `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
aa <- c(1022011, 2022011, 13022011, 23022011)
> dmy(aa)
[1] "2011-02-01 UTC" "2011-02-02 UTC" "2011-02-13 UTC" "2011-02-23 UTC"
```

and if you don't want the timezone just wrap it in `as.Date`:

```
> as.Date(dmy(aa))
[1] "2011-02-01" "2011-02-02" "2011-02-13" "2011-02-23"
```

Thank you @Ben Bolker,

```
> as.Date(mdy(aa))
[1] "2011-01-02" "2011-02-02" "2012-01-02" "2011-01-02"
```

Comment: This is not working in case of `aa <- c(1022011, 2232011, 12232011, 2272011)` where the format is mmddyyyy. Returning wrong values. Can't we somehow specify the format in `dmy`?

Comment: yup. mdy worked. Thanks always good to know about new functions.

Comment: @Ben Bolker Thank you. @user3664020 `lubridate` has a lot of useful functions like the above, such as `ymd_hms` and similar enumerations for date-time classes.

Comment: @nrussell `as.Date(mdy(aa))` is giving me funny dates for the 3rd and 4th elements in `aa` (i.e., "2012-01-02" "2062-10-21"). You seem to have other dates for the elements. Do you have any guess for this funny behaviour?

Comment: @jazzurro I'm not sure why that's happening on your machine, I just reran `as.Date(mdy(aa))` and `as.Date(dmy(aa))` with the `aa` vector in my example and it returned normal dates.

Comment: @nrussell `as.Date(dmy(aa))` works fine on my machine as well. Seeing the output of your `as.Date(mdy(aa))`, I thought the 3rd and 4th date turned to be wrong dates. Do you still have them? Or do you have an identical outcome between `as.Date(dmy(aa))` and `as.Date(mdy(aa))`?

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to add a "0" but still, in base R, this works :

```
as.Date(sapply(aa,function(x){ifelse(nchar(x)==8,x,paste("0",x,sep=""))}),format = "%d%m%Y")
```