# Convert UTC Time in R

Tags: r, utc, strptime

I have a data column with UTC Time, the format is 'Tue Apr 03 18:00:09 +0000 2012' in R. May I know can I convert this into Date? I need to ultimately plot frequency by date and I'm not sure how to do it.

Please advise! Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301204/r-converting-date-and-time-fields-to-posixct-with-hhmmss-format) for ideas?

Comment: or mebbe `?strptime` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- 'Tue Apr 03 18:00:09 +0000 2012'
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%a %b %d %T %z %Y")
```

`%a` is an abbreviated weekday name, `%b` is an abbreviated month name, `%d` is the month day number(01-31), `%T` is the 24 hour time stamp, `%z` is the signed UTC offset, and `%Y` is the full year.

Ultimately, you need to group your dataframe by date and count occurrence, so perhaps you should use `as.Date` instead of `as.POSIXct`.